# Fuzzy smart number parsing in Python

Tags: python, parsing, fuzzy

I wish to parse *decimal* numbers regardless of their format, which is unknown. Language of the original text is unknown and may vary. In addition, the source string can contain some extra text before or after, like currency or units.

I'm using the following:

```
# NOTE: Do not use, this algorithm is buggy. See below.
def extractnumber(value):

    if (isinstance(value, int)): return value
    if (isinstance(value, float)): return value

    result = re.sub(r'&#\d+', '', value)
    result = re.sub(r'[^0-9\,\.]', '', result)

    if (len(result) == 0): return None

    numPoints = result.count('.')
    numCommas = result.count(',')

    result = result.replace(",", ".")

    if ((numPoints > 0 and numCommas > 0) or (numPoints == 1) or (numCommas == 1)):
        decimalPart = result.split(".")[-1]
        integerPart = "".join ( result.split(".")[0:-1] )
    else:
        integerPart = result.replace(".", "")

    result = int(integerPart) + (float(decimalPart) / pow(10, len(decimalPart) ))

    return result
```

This kind of works...

```
>>> extractnumber("2")
2
>>> extractnumber("2.3")
2.3
>>> extractnumber("2,35")
2.35
>>> extractnumber("-2 000,5")
-2000.5
>>> extractnumber("EUR 1.000,74 €")
1000.74

>>> extractnumber("20,5 20,8") # Testing failure...
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '205 208'

>>> extractnumber("20.345.32.231,50") # Returns false positive
2034532231.5
```

So my method seems very fragile to me, and returns lots of false positives.

Is there any library or smart function that can handle this? Ideally `20.345.32.231,50` shall not pass, but numbers in other languages like `1.200,50` or `1 200'50` would be extracted, regardless the amount of other text and characters (including newlines) around.

(Updated implementation according to accepted answer: 
https://github.com/jjmontesl/cubetl/blob/master/cubetl/text/functions.py#L91)

Comment: What output do you expect from `123 456`? `123456` or `[123, 456]`?

Comment: :) Let me edit and remove the multiple numbers part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with a suitably fancy regular expression. Here's my best attempt at one. I use named capturing groups, as with a pattern this complex, numeric ones would be much more confusing to use in backreferences.

First, the regexp pattern:

```
_pattern = r"""(?x)       # enable verbose mode (which ignores whitespace and comments)
    ^                     # start of the input
    [^\d+-\.]*            # prefixed junk
    (?P<number>           # capturing group for the whole number
        (?P<sign>[+-])?       # sign group (optional)
        (?P<integer_part>         # capturing group for the integer part
            \d{1,3}               # leading digits in an int with a thousands separator
            (?P<sep>              # capturing group for the thousands separator
                [ ,.]                 # the allowed separator characters
            )
            \d{3}                 # exactly three digits after the separator
            (?:                   # non-capturing group
                (?P=sep)              # the same separator again (a backreference)
                \d{3}                 # exactly three more digits
            )*                    # repeated 0 or more times
        |                     # or
            \d+                   # simple integer (just digits with no separator)
        )?                    # integer part is optional, to allow numbers like ".5"
        (?P<decimal_part>     # capturing group for the decimal part of the number
            (?P<point>            # capturing group for the decimal point
                (?(sep)               # conditional pattern, only tested if sep matched
                    (?!                   # a negative lookahead
                        (?P=sep)              # backreference to the separator
                    )
                )
                [.,]                  # the accepted decimal point characters
            )
            \d+                   # one or more digits after the decimal point
        )?                    # the whole decimal part is optional
    )
    [^\d]*                # suffixed junk
    $                     # end of the input
"""
```

And here's a function to use it:

```
def parse_number(text):
    match = re.match(_pattern, text)
    if match is None or not (match.group("integer_part") or
                             match.group("decimal_part")):    # failed to match
        return None                      # consider raising an exception instead

    num_str = match.group("number")      # get all of the number, without the junk
    sep = match.group("sep")
    if sep:
        num_str = num_str.replace(sep, "")     # remove thousands separators

    if match.group("decimal_part"):
        point = match.group("point")
        if point != ".":
            num_str = num_str.replace(point, ".")  # regularize the decimal point
        return float(num_str)

    return int(num_str)
```

Some numeric strings with exactly one comma or period and exactly three digits following it (like `"1,234"` and `"1.234"`) are ambiguous. This code will parse both of them as integers with a thousand separator (`1234`), rather than floating point values (`1.234`) regardless of the actual separator character used. It's possible you could handle this with a special case, if you want a different outcome for those numbers (e.g. if you'd prefer to make a float out of `1.234`).

Some test output:

```
>>> test_cases = ["2", "2.3", "2,35", "-2 000,5", "EUR 1.000,74 €",
                  "20,5 20,8", "20.345.32.231,50", "1.234"]
>>> for s in test_cases:
    print("{!r:20}: {}".format(s, parse_number(s)))


'2'                 : 2
'2.3'               : 2.3
'2,35'              : 2.35
'-2 000,5'          : -2000.5
'EUR 1.000,74 €'    : 1000.74
'20,5 20,8'         : None
'20.345.32.231,50'  : None
'1.234'             : 1234
```

Comment: Awesome, how do you build these? by hand?

Comment: This one I did build by hand, yeah. It wasn't originally in "verbose" mode. The separate parts (sign, int part, decimal part) were in separate strings to start with. But verbose mode sure helped with debugging and explaining it! The only really subtle part of the pattern was the conditional negative lookahead that prevents the decimal point from being the same character as the thousands separator. That makes sure that a string like `"1,234,56"` won't me matched as `1234.56`. Oh, and I only added support for numbers with no integer part (like `.5`) right at the end.

Comment: Fantastic, I implemented your solution adding an exception for the 1.234 case (I preferred it to be decimal). Final version on its final place: https://github.com/jjmontesl/cubetl/blob/master/src/cubetl/functions/text.py#L31

Comment: Also, I ran the old and new versions on over 40000 documents comparing to mine and it detected a failure in my version ('0,06'  parsed as '-0.06'). So my algorithm fails and cannot be used in any case :), yours rocks.

Comment: A great solution with comprehensive comments! Very educative.

Answer (score 2):

I refacored your code a bit. This, together with the `valid_number` function below should do the trick.

**The main reason I took time to write this awful piece of code though, is to show future readers how awful parsing regular expressions can get if you don't know how to use regexp (like me for instance).**

Hopefully, someone who know regexp better than me can show us how it **should** be done :)

## Constrains

- `.`, `,` and `'` is accepted as both thousand separator and decimal
  separator
- Not more than two different separators
- Maximum one separators with more than one occurrence
- Separator treated as decimal separators if only one separator present, and only one of that kind. (i.e. `123,456` are interpreted as `123.456`, not `123456`)
- String is split up to list of numbers by double space (`'  '`)
- All parts of a thousand-separated number except for the first part, is required to be 3 digits long (`123,456.00` and `1,345.00` are both considered valid, but `2345,11.00` is not considered vald)

## Code

`import re`

`from itertools import combinations`

```
def extract_number(value):
    if (isinstance(value, int)) or (isinstance(value, float)):
        yield float(value)
    else:
        #Strip the string for leading and trailing whitespace
        value = value.strip()
        if len(value) == 0:
            raise StopIteration
        for s in value.split('  '):
            s = re.sub(r'&#\d+', '', s)
            s = re.sub(r'[^\-\s0-9\,\.]', ' ', s)
            s = s.replace(' ', '')
            if len(s) == 0:
                continue
            if not valid_number(s):
                continue
            if not sum(s.count(sep) for sep in [',', '.', '\'']):
                yield float(s)
            else:
                s = s.replace('.', '@').replace('\'', '@').replace(',', '@')
                integer, decimal = s.rsplit('@', 1)
                integer = integer.replace('@', '')
                s = '.'.join([integer, decimal])
                yield float(s)
```

**Well - here comes the code that could probably be replaced by a couple of regexp statements.**

```
def valid_number(s):
    def _correct_integer(integer):
        # First number should have length of 1-3
        if not (0 < len(integer[0].replace('-', '')) < 4):
            return False
        # All the rest of the integers should be of length 3
        for num in integer[1:]:
            if len(num) != 3:
                return False
        return True
    seps = ['.', ',', '\'']
    n_seps = [s.count(k) for k in seps]

    # If no separator is present
    if sum(n_seps) == 0:
        return True

    # If all separators are present
    elif all(n_seps):
        return False

    # If two separators are present
    elif any(all(c) for c in combinations(n_seps, 2)):
        # Find thousand separator
        for c in s:
            if c in seps:
                tho_sep = c
                break

        # Find decimal separator:
        for c in reversed(s):
            if c in seps:
                dec_sep = c
                break

        s = s.split(dec_sep)

        # If it is more than one decimal separator
        if len(s) != 2:
            return False

        integer = s[0].split(tho_sep)

        return _correct_integer(integer)

    # If one separator is present, and it is more than one of it
    elif sum(n_seps) > 1:
        for sep in seps:
            if sep in s:
                s = s.split(sep)
                break
        return _correct_integer(s)

    # Otherwise, this is a regular decimal number
    else:
        return True
```

## Output

```
extract_number('2'                  ):  [2.0]
extract_number('.2'                 ):  [0.2]
extract_number(2                    ):  [2.0]
extract_number(0.2                  ):  [0.2]
extract_number('EUR 200'            ):  [200.0]
extract_number('EUR 200.00  -11.2'  ):  [200.0, -11.2]
extract_number('EUR 200  EUR 300'   ):  [200.0, 300.0]
extract_number('$ -1.000,22'        ):   [-1000.22]
extract_number('EUR 100.2345,3443'  ):  []
extract_number('111,145,234.345.345'):  []
extract_number('20,5  20,8'         ):  [20.5, 20.8]
extract_number('20.345.32.231,50'   ):  []
```

Comment: Multiple commas and points are valid, as some languages use . for thousands separator and , for decimals. Some other use ' for decimals, which ideally would be accepted too. For those languages, grouping shall be always done in blocks of 3 figures: 1.245.000,50 is valid Spanish.

Comment: Including spaces, I'd like to accept multiple numbers if separate numbers are clearly spaced by more than one space or other text, but accepting multiple numbers is not really something I need.

Comment: Ok, the you should read up on more advanced regexp :) I'm don't have much experience in the field, but I found [this](http://bit.ly/17QbFZj) link that might help you on your way.