# Defining a financial number with a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

The following are valid numbers for various financial displays depending on the region, etc:

```
1,000
1000.00
1,000,000.00
2.000.000,00
123748 # without commas
4 294 967 295,000
0.24
.24
24
24.
```

What would be a better approach to finding a regex for the above, doing one large regex or multiple regexes for each pattern? For example, an individual pattern being like:

```
no_thousands_separator = '\d+[.,]?\d{0,3}?
```

Comment: Wat exactly do you want to match? Should `4 294 967 295,000` be a whole match? Is this the only value that you want to match or could it also be part of a larger text?

Comment: This is probably too complicated of a problem for regex to handle alone, if you want to cover all your bases. Take a look at the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-currency-string-in-javascript and maybe consider using something like this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat

Comment: Some answers can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157375/fuzzy-smart-number-parsing-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely want to design some expression, not exactly, but maybe similar to,

```
^\.?(?:(?:\d{1,3}[,. ])*\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{2})?|\d+\.\d+|\d+)\.?$
```

One way to design that is to look for your most complicated pattern, write an expression, alter, then continue to your simplest pattern.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/X7WxqT/1/)

I've just added two `\.?` in the beginning and end of the expression, but that's not really right, you are going to incorporate those wherever you want to.

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/X7WxqT/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/X7WxqT/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### [This expression would not validate, but only pass those numbers](https://regex101.com/r/aXso7i/1/).

Answer (score 1):

You can make one regex, to keep things more simple:

```
\d*(?:([., ])(?:\d{3}\1)*\d{3})?(?:[.,]\d*)?
```

[Inspect on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/FouK3y/1)

How does this work?

```
\d*          Where numbers can occur
([., ])?     Capture the thousands separator
\d{3}        Match 3 digits between separators
\1           Recall thousands separator
(?:[.,]\d*)? Optionally capures decimal part (no thousands separator allowed here)
```

Answer (score 0):

Play with regex below:

```
function parseNum(str) {
   const match = /^[\d.,\s]+$/.exec(str);

   return match ? match[0] : null;
}
```